# Push notify doesn't arrive

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, apk

I build an android app composed by a web view, in parse.com i've got my device registered but when i send a push notification in "pushes sent" there is 0 pushes.
this is my Mainactivity:

```
import com.party.bparty.MainActivity;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String url = "http://www.bestparty.altervista.org";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //attivo parse per le notifiche
        Parse.initialize(this,"zJxpd9798Ns6A9rzUDpe78ElRY0I99ES3LD6nDQV","kmAmA1iTbC32BTE9ERtzNOoHXbJchhIn6tyPXKMi");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        //...
        //...initializing and loading the contentview and the webview
    }

    //options menu omitted
}
```

this is my MycustomReceiver

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent == null)
                Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
            else {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action );
                if (action.equals("com.party.bparty.UPDATE_STATUS")) {
                    String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

                    Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
                    Iterator itr = json.keys();
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        String key = (String) itr.next();
                        if (key.equals("customdata")) {
                            Intent pupInt = new Intent(context, ShowPopUp.class);
                            pupInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(pupInt);
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my ShowPopup

```
public class ShowPopUp extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button ok, cancel;
    boolean click = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Cupon");
        setContentView(R.layout.popupdialog);
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.popOkB);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.popCancelB);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

And this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.party.bparty"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.party.bparty.ShowPopUp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.party.bparty.MyCustomReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.iakremera.pushnotificationdemo.UPDATE_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where's my error?

I do it, but it doesn't work anyway
"            if (action.equals("com.party.bparty.UPDATE_STATUS")) {
Pick one, either com.party.bparty.UPDATE_STATUS or com.iakremera.pushnotificationdemo.UPDATE_STATUS"
but Now i have 1 "PUSH SENT" in push sent, but my device doesn't show any push

Comment: can you see the status of the message when you send one?? (when i send push message from terminal i can see the status 'success' etc.)

Comment: how are you sending the notification?

Comment: parse.com -> send a push

Comment: i think PushService.setDefaultPushCallback is deprecated.
try replacing it with:
PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this);
and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver has the wrong filter. Your receiver is declared as this:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.party.bparty.MyCustomReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.iakremera.pushnotificationdemo.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but you are checking for a different intent action in the code:

```
            if (action.equals("com.party.bparty.UPDATE_STATUS")) {
```

Pick one, either `com.party.bparty.UPDATE_STATUS` or `com.iakremera.pushnotificationdemo.UPDATE_STATUS` and also make sure that Parse knows which one it is when you perform the push itself.